# How to get clicked time serie from dygraph in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I have a dygraph plot with multiple time series in R Shiny. What I would like to do is to retrieve the time serie identfier when I click on 1 of these time series, so that I can use this time serie Id in my shiny application.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Here is an example of code (ui.R and server.R of how I could use it, just in case it is similar with what we can do with plotly and event_data.
(I know that this code cannot work as event_data does not exist for dygraph)

**ui.R**

```html
library(dygraphs)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Predicted Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dygraphOutput("dygraph"),
      verbatimTextOutput("selected")
    )
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```html
library(dygraphs)
library(datasets)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  lungDeaths <- cbind(ldeaths, mdeaths, fdeaths)
  
  output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({
    
    dygraph(lungDeaths, main = "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)") %>%
      dyHighlight(highlightCircleSize = 5, 
                  highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha = 0.2,
                  hideOnMouseOut = FALSE) %>%
      dyOptions(drawGrid = input$showgrid)
    
  })
  
  output$selected <- renderPrint({
    ts <- event_data("clicked")
    if (! is.null(ts))
      return(ts)
  })
  
})
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: should be doable. Can you share a simple example app.

Comment: plotly and event_data might be easier for this...